# How can I use Wagtail Forms for a Headless CMS? ( without Template )

Tags: django, wagtail, headless-cms, wagtail-apiv2

According to the documentation, Wagtail API is read-only ( POST Method not allowed ). Hence, the only way to use Forms from the [Sidebar Menu](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/editor_manual/finding_your_way_around/the_explorer_menu.html) is [using Templates](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-build-form-page-wagtail/), so the client is capable of making post requests against the API internaly. But that´s not headless. To be headless the API must be capable of receiving form data by providing a URL.

> [Wagtail Docs - API](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html)
>
> "The Wagtail API module exposes a public, read only, JSON-formatted API which can be used by external clients (such as a mobile app) or the site’s frontend."
>
> ...

At this point I´m not having the slightest clue, that means at a last resort I have to rethink my stack, although so far I have been very satisfied with Wagtail as headless CMS together with Nuxt as Client. Any ideas to avoid this measure would be much apprechiated.

### Update - Nuxt POST Request to Wagtail API v2

```
pages/index.vue

<template>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
  },
  async asyncData ({ $axios, req }) {
    const pageHome = await $axios.$get('https://foo.bar.com/api/v2/pages/3/')
    return { pageHome }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue. `GET` a form is easy as a standard page.  Have no idea how to `POST`.

Comment: @JunmingWang For development purpose just disable the CSRF middleware, so you can `POST` without Token. For production Django CSRF-mechanism has to be installed, which will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

I like the depth of you research but don't think you necessarily have to take a complete turn on your stack. I use exactly the same technologies but on forms you have to just use plain of [Django Rest Framework serializers & generic class based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) to handle common cases like [ListCreateAPIView and RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) for heavy lifting.

Even though this approach involves quite a bit of coding you'll still be much better off writing your own API views to handle form data and there's no new plugins needed to pull it off.

Afterthought, if you need to have form attachments you can use this [flexible method](https://medium.com/ibisdev/upload-multiple-images-to-a-model-with-django-fd00d8551a1c) of creating your form model and to get your form responses in excel or csv you can use [Django Admin Import/Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-via-admin-action).

I hope this eliminates the need for you to throw away the baby & bath water.

Comment: This looks like a solid approach, so I will take a closer look. But I also found out that the POST-Requests are not working because they don´t have a CSRF-Cookie set. Hopefully this means that I don't have to change too much in the code.

Comment: Are you POSTing like a normal HTML fmutli-part orm or performing an actual REST POST call using Django Rest Framework - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ ?

Comment: Above I added my request from the Nuxt client to the Wagtail API ( which fails due to missing CSRF-Token; 403: Forbiden ). This API is based on the Django API. The request header is set to content-type: applicatoin/json.

When using the regular non-headless Wagtail form ( which works well; 200 ), the content-type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Think when CSRF ist set up correctly I also have to adjust the request header, so it look like this one already build in.

Comment: Can you send code samples, I'm failing to understand what you mean.

Comment: As expacted the request header (from the client with different URL) has to be setup like the request which would come from Django template (if it wasn´t headless cms). That means content-type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded with the fitting data scheme. But that´s incidental. Mainly it´s about setting up the CSRF-mechanism. My dare idea (for production) is to store the CSRFToken (created by Django) in an environment variable, pick it up by the Nuxt-Client and use it for authorising (when executing `POST` request)